# How come grep can get minimum number of characters per line but not maximum?

Tags: grep, macos

I am able to do this in Bash on a Mac:

```
grep ".\{81,\}" foo.txt
```

to get all lines with 81 characters or more for the file `foo.txt`, and use:

```
grep -v ".\{81,\}" foo.txt
```

to get all line with 80 characters or less. (`-v` for the "opposite")

But if I use

```
grep ".\{,81\}" foo.txt
```

it would say `grep: invalid repetition count(s)`.

And if I use

```
grep ".\{0,81\}" foo.txt
```

it would give all lines no matter the length.

How would the above last two forms be made to work? They follow the regular expression form of

```
.{,80}
```

meaning any number of characters 80 or less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep ".\{0,81\}" foo.txt
```

Any line will match this. If line has 82 characters, it also has 81 characters. You need to either:

- wrap the regex in `^` and `$` so that, from start of line to end of line, there are between 0 and 81 characters, or
- use `-x` to specify that the line must exactly match this regex (equivalent to the above option)

So:

```
grep "^.\{0,81\}$" foo.txt
grep -x ".\{0,81\}" foo.txt
```

Comment: great.  what about the form `.{,80}`

Comment: @nopole I don't think `{,n}` is valid ([POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) allows `\{m\}`, `\{m,\}`, or `\{m,n\}` in BREs and `{m}`, `{m,}`, or `{m,n}`, in EREs). GNU grep allows `{,n}` with `-E`.

Comment: actually, I tried `grep -E "^.\{,80\}$"` and it didn't work (nothing is output).

Comment: @nopole With `-E`, you need to use `{0,80}`, not `\{0,80\}`. And `{,81}` is with GNU grep. Your default macOS grep probably won't understand it.

Comment: if there is a PCRE version of grep it might be good... but then I guess we can always use `perl -e " ... "` or `php` to do something

Comment: @nopole with GNU grep, `-P` uses PCRE. Maybe you should just install GNU grep using homebrew.

Comment: thanks... I am also exploring the one line version of perl: `perl -wnle "/^.{0,80}$/ and print"`

Comment: sometimes I hesitate to use homebrew as I wonder whether to trust it enough, but then I think with `rvm` or `npm install` it is similar situations

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ printf 'abcdef\nABC\n' | awk 'length($0) > 3'
abcdef
$ printf 'abcdef\nABC\n' | awk 'length($0) < 3'
$
$ printf 'abcdef\nABC\n' | awk 'length($0) <= 3'
ABC
```

Keep it simple and remember [the saying](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.